# Could we have in python web page generated as in php?

Tags: python, web

***Can we write in python language (or maybe exist such a web framework), that we could write Python and html tags as in PHP language.***

Could we have such a python file structure:

**some_python_file.py:**

```
<html>
<head>
     <title>Lol</title>
<head>
<body>
    My PyWeb Slang
</body>
</html>

<!-- this part should be python -->
<?py
    from Eternity import Kiss

    love = Kiss.Forever()
    print "%s" % love
?>
```

sorry i'm writting with caps: **DISAMBIGUATION:**

You can see, that template use in each line {% goodies %} or <%= goodies %>

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
  <ul>
  {% for user in users %}
    <li><a href="{{ user.url }}">{{ user.username }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

**But in PHP:**

```
<div>Good Morning, Sun!</div>
<?php

     echo "Happy!";
     echo "Hi, WaterLand!";

?>
```

**If Python could do it that way, it should be like:**

```
<div>Good Morning, Sun!</div>

<?py

     print "%s" % "Happy!"
     print "%s" % "Hi, WaterLand!";

?>
```

Got the ideia, or I need to be more explicit?

Thank You. :)

**Hm, if so:**

Could we write with mod_python something like (extending **[morphyn]** example from below):

```
<html>
<%
    greet = 'Hello Wee!'
    answer = 'Hello Bee!'
%>
<h1><%= greet %></h1>
<h2><%= answer %></h2>
</html>
```

There you can see more than 2'u lines into <% ... %>
Could we?

Comment: There is at least one framework that allows basically this, but it is necessarily slow, and can't be client-side (since you can't be sure clients will have Python).

Comment: nope. Python ISNT php. use templates for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not exactly what you're asking for, but the proper way to do this is to use a template engine. Take a look at [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/). [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/templates/) also provides its own template engine.

**Update:**

By default, Python cannot be embedded in HTML pages. There is however at least one way of doing it. `mod_python`, a module for Apache2, offers the kind of feature you want with [PSP](http://www.modpython.org/live/mod_python-3.1.2b/doc-html/pyapi-psp.html) (Python Server Pages).

```
<html>
<%
    greet = 'Hello'
%>
<h1><%= greet %></h1>
</html>
```

Keep in mind that mixing logic and presentation is generally not a good idea. The proper way to go is still to use a template engine, as stated in my original answer. You may have very good reasons to do what you want to do, but probably not.

Comment: +1 lots of frameworks exists that come with templating engines that does what the OP is asking for :) Tornado, CherryPy, gunicorn and more

Comment: Could you please confirm or disapprove what i'm asking at the end of question (updated). Thank You.

NOTE: i could look into google, but for the pleasure of discution :)

Thank You. :)

Comment: Yes, you can write standard Python between the <% %> (pay attention at how the indentation is interpreted though).

Comment: Thank You for the hint.

And yes, i saw Mako also. Thx U.

Answer (score 1):

[web.py](http://webpy.org/) works similarly to the way you want, but kind of backwards. You use URLs to call classes and the classes can render templates that can have parameters passed in order to populate content when the template is rendered into an html page. I think it is simpler to use than [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/), but if you have a lot of content changing all the time, it might be the way to go. The following is a code example from the web.py website that shows how simple it is.

```
import web

urls = (
    '/(.*)', 'hello'
)
app = web.application(urls, globals())

class hello:        
    def GET(self, name):
        if not name: 
            name = 'World'
        return 'Hello, ' + name + '!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: Thank You, Web2py, Django, etc. are wonderful, but, please :), catch the ideia i'am asking on.

See examples :)

Comment: Sorry, i was thinking you're telling about: Web2py, but you mean - http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/tutorial#templating

Answer (score 0):

**Yes:** We can use **PSP** (Python Server Pages) **[User:morphyn answer]**

[Paul Osman : Introduction to mod_python](http://goo.gl/CZ7YS)

**Example from article:**

```
<%
    a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    for number in a:
%>
This is a number: <%=number %> <br />
<%
    # this terminates the iteration
%>
<h1>Hello</h1>
```